# Looking for help to sort out DIY array method in PhP

Tags: php, arrays

I need helps on the PhP array method deployed below:

Actual PhP code:

```
$itemsB = array("Steve Jobs"=>"USA", "Thomas Edison"=>"USA");
echo $itemsB['Steve Jobs'];
echo '<br />';
echo $itemsB['Thomas Edison'];
```

Expected Result: 
USA
USA

---

Created DIY method below base on the above and hope to retrieve the same result but failed (getting no output)? The reason I am using this DIY method due to I have a list of Profile Data that need to fill into the conventional array method of : $items = array('name1'=>'value1', 'name2'=>'value2');

```
$ProfileName[0] = "\"Steve Jobs\"=>\"USA\"";
 $ProfileName[1] = "\"Thomas Edison\"=>\"USA\"";

 $items = array("$ProfileName[0]", "$ProfileName[1]");
 echo $items['Steve Jobs'];
 echo '<br />';
 echo $items['Thomas Edison'];
```

Please advice!
Cheers

---

Alright, brief updates on what I am looking for if you still find unclear on the above. Below is the code to search Profile Name for autocomplete method on text field box. The code below is working if I entered the static values into the array. But, I have a list of Profile Names in the Database that I wanted to populate and add it into the array below. Thus, I thought of do some DIY that shown above. Unless there is other solution for this. Please advice

```
$q = strtolower($_GET["q"]);
if (!$q) return;

$items = array("Steve Jobs"=>"USA", "Thomas Edison"=>"USA");

foreach ($items as $key=>$value) {
    if (strpos(strtolower($key), $q) !== false) {
        echo "$key|$value\n";
    }//END IF
}//END FOR
```

Comment: How are you getting the names and locations? Are you setting each as a variable? if so you could just do something like `foreach($value as $v){$items[$v[0]] = $v[1];}` or something to that effect. It depends on how you have things set up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you, if I'm understanding your question correctly:

```
 $ProfileName[0] = 'Steve Jobs|USA';
 $ProfileName[1] = 'Thomas Edison|USA';

 $items = array();

 foreach($ProfileName as $p){
    $items[substr($p,0,strpos($p,'|'))] = substr($p,strpos($p,'|')+1,strlen($p));
 }

  print_r($items);
 echo $items['Steve Jobs'];
 echo '<br />';
 echo $items['Thomas Edison'];
```

This seems like a long way around to get to the same place, but you could try something like this.

Or something like this could help if you're pulling stuff from the database:

```
$db = new mysqli('host','user','password','db-name');

if ($result = $db->query("SELECT name,location FROM `table`"))
    {
        if ($result->num_rows > 0)
        {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
            {
                $items[$row->name] = $row->location;
            }
        }
    }
 echo $items['Steve Jobs'];
 echo '<br />';
 echo $items['Thomas Edison'];
```

Comment: Hi John, thanks for the answer. That's the working code, but I intend to use the other example where I have list of Profile Data to fill up into this: $items = array("$ProfileName[0]", "$ProfileName[1]"); but it seems not working. Please advice! Cheers

Comment: That's about the only way it'll work. If you use print_r you'll see this as the result for what you're doing: `Array ( [0] => "Steve Jobs"=>"USA" [1] => "Thomas Edison"=>"USA" )`. Maybe if you explained what you were doing a little more we could help out. The question is a bit vague.

Comment: Hi Marinara & John, Thanks for the comment and I have updated my question above and please tell me if you guys can help me to find out the new solution or base on my DIY method. Cheers

Comment: @user1109161 - Updated the answer... hopefully to something that you were thinking.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for the update Answer. Managed to tweak it base on your example. Much appreciated. Cheers